# Nested Menu Items with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I'm writing an application with WPF using MVVM and now I have problems building a nested menu:

I've got two objects named ThumbnailDocument and ThumbnailPage. In my ViewModel I've got an ObservableCollection of ThumbnailDocuments and in ThumbnailDocuments I've got an ObservableCollection of ThumbnailPage

Here is the code:

ViewModel class:

```
public class ThumbnailPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection<ThumbnailDocument> Documents
    {
        get { return this._CurrentlyLoadedDocs; }
    }
}
```

ThumbnailDocument class:

```
public class ThumbnailDocument : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{ 
    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection<ThumbnailPage> ThumbnailPages
    {
        get { return _ThumbnailPages; }
    }

    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
}
```

ThumbnailPage class:

```
public class ThumbnailPage : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public int PageNumber { get; private set; }
}
```

Now I want to create a nested menu with this structure:

Header Entry --> All document titles --> For each document which I hover over the page number

eg: Header Entry -->

1. Document 1

   ```
          --> Page 1
          --> Page 2
          --> Page 3
   ```
2. Document 2

   ```
          --> Page 1
          --> Page 2
   ```

I hope this example was clear.

I've written this XAML parts but it does not work:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource thumbnailViewModel}, Path=Ctx_Move_Pages}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MovePages_MenuItemContainerStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource thumbnailViewModel}, Path=LoadedDocuments}">                                    
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="ThumbnailDocument">
            <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding ThumbnailPages}">
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding PageNumber}"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource MovePageSmall}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

And the style:

```
<Style x:Key="MovePages_MenuItemContainerStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="MovePages_MenuItem_Clicked" />
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DocumentTitle}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Do you have some ideas how I can get this running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to display hierarchical data in WPF is to use the [`HierarchicalDataTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This class extends the `DataTemplate` class and adds the essential `ItemsSource` property. Using this property, you can define which collection property to use to represent the child objects:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourClass}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding YourChildCollectionProperty}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Please see the [`HierarchicalDataTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for a code example and full description of this class.

Comment: Thanks, after much trial and error I've got it with this HierarchicalDataTemplate